# Spread by Two Columns

Tags: r, dataframe, spread

I am trying to spread a data frame, but I am not quite familiar with `spread()` and `gather()`.

Below is a sample of my data. It has 9 rows all with the same `Application.Number`. I would like to end up with one row per `Application.Number-Decicion` combination. The remaining variables `date_generated` `date_decided` `time_to_decision` and `text` have to be repeated for each `Application.Number-Decicion` combination or the last one should be taken. The data is already sorted by `Application.Number` and `date_generated`.

```
structure(list(Application.Number = c(80749L, 80749L, 80749L, 
80749L, 80749L, 80749L, 80749L, 80749L, 80749L), Decision = c("Invalid", 
"Invalid", "Invalid", "Invalid", "Invalid", "Invalid", "Approved", 
"Approved", "Approved"), date_generated = structure(c(1521810060, 
1521810060, 1523523840, 1523536500, 1524036720, 1524136380, 1524137460, 
1524137460, 1524137460), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    date_decided = structure(c(1522155960, 1522155660, 1523534400, 
    1523600520, 1524127140, 1524136740, 1524211800, 1524211740, 
    1524211200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    time_to_decision = c(4.00347222222222, 4, 0.122222222222222, 
    0.740972222222222, 1.04652777777778, 0.00416666666666667, 
    0.860416666666667, 0.859722222222222, 0.853472222222222), 
    text = c("rIUQRmOkyZ", "ZxdYUr16NR", "8IIipoleOV", "nLuIgToxcT", 
    "xYFksrws87", "N2oECMtgQo", "RKcrBcBFI2", "jaH438byVt", "80ggA2hZr7"
    )), row.names = 15880:15888, class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT: Decided that the output should be just one row and all rows should pivot around `Application.Number`.

I ended up making a separate data frame with the duplicates and joining it back to the unique rows.

There must be a better way to do it.

Comment: Can u show the expected output

Comment: I think this is an XY question. (i.e. querying how to do X when you should be doing Y.) You should not be trying to spread data that has such irregular structure. Instead you should be using lists or learning how to manage data in long format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do it, but I agree with user 42-, it will lead to problems because of data format later:

```
> gather(x, "key", "val", -Application.Number, -Decision)
   Application.Number Decision              key                 val
1               80749  Invalid   date_generated          1521810060
2               80749  Invalid   date_generated          1521810060
3               80749  Invalid   date_generated          1523523840
4               80749  Invalid   date_generated          1523536500
5               80749  Invalid   date_generated          1524036720
6               80749  Invalid   date_generated          1524136380
7               80749 Approved   date_generated          1524137460
8               80749 Approved   date_generated          1524137460
9               80749 Approved   date_generated          1524137460
10              80749  Invalid     date_decided          1522155960
11              80749  Invalid     date_decided          1522155660
12              80749  Invalid     date_decided          1523534400
13              80749  Invalid     date_decided          1523600520
14              80749  Invalid     date_decided          1524127140
15              80749  Invalid     date_decided          1524136740
16              80749 Approved     date_decided          1524211800
17              80749 Approved     date_decided          1524211740
18              80749 Approved     date_decided          1524211200
19              80749  Invalid time_to_decision    4.00347222222222
20              80749  Invalid time_to_decision                   4
21              80749  Invalid time_to_decision   0.122222222222222
22              80749  Invalid time_to_decision   0.740972222222222
23              80749  Invalid time_to_decision    1.04652777777778
24              80749  Invalid time_to_decision 0.00416666666666667
25              80749 Approved time_to_decision   0.860416666666667
26              80749 Approved time_to_decision   0.859722222222222
27              80749 Approved time_to_decision   0.853472222222222
28              80749  Invalid             text          rIUQRmOkyZ
29              80749  Invalid             text          ZxdYUr16NR
30              80749  Invalid             text          8IIipoleOV
31              80749  Invalid             text          nLuIgToxcT
32              80749  Invalid             text          xYFksrws87
33              80749  Invalid             text          N2oECMtgQo
34              80749 Approved             text          RKcrBcBFI2
35              80749 Approved             text          jaH438byVt
36              80749 Approved             text          80ggA2hZr7
Warning:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped
```

The warning already is a hint: You have converted all your value columns `data_generated`, `date_decided`, `time_to_decision` and `text` to the most general data format which can hold all these values: Character strings. See how your dates were converted to *seconds since the epoch*: You lost for example time zone information.

So in short, you can do it but I don't think you should. Because you did not show your use case or any context, I can't propose a better solution though.,

Comment: Thanks. The use case is to have all the info about an application in a single row. From there, I can decide whether to pick the first, second, etc. instance of the variables related to this one application.